# in R, how do I quote a comment using quote or bquote?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

```r
quote(# this is a comment)
```

How can I do something like the above?

Comment: Comment is not a code so you cannot quote it. Presenting your full use case could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quote()` captures the original code in its `wholeSrcref` attribute, which preserves comments:

```
x <- quote({
    ## This is a comment
})

src <- attributes(x)$wholeSrcref          # <--- preserves the comment
```

However, this returns an object of class `srcref`, not a true expression that can be passed to `eval()`. Depending on what you are trying to do, you may find [these functions for manipulating srcref objects](http://web.mit.edu/r/current/lib/R/library/base/html/srcfile.html) useful. For example,

```
as.character(src)[2]
[1] "    ## This is a comment"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve, but the following things should work:

1. You can easily store hashtags within strings:

   `string<- "# this is a comment"`
2. If you need to put this in quotes you can do:

   `dQuote("# this is a comment",q = options(useFancyQuotes=FALSE))`

This returns: `"\"# this is a comment\""` .

The option `useFancyQuotes=FALSE` is making sure that "normal" quotes (and not typographic quotes) are used. If you leave this parameter out the result would be `"“# this is a comment”"`

3. You can also just write `quote("# this is a comment")` which will return `"# this is a comment"`